Mobile and Web application Architecture: React Native, Django, Postgres and Supabase
Want to build a side project so let me give you a bit of the scope before diving into my proposed architecture and how I can get them to play nice.
It's a market place where partners can create accounts and login only through a website (they are businesses decisions why this is the case).
Buyers can only login through a provided mobile application, built in React Native.
My primarily server side technology is Django built on a postgres database. This will hold a lot of the server side functionality and host the API the mobile application will be consuming.
Now I have been looking at a few BaaS and the two that stick out are FireBase and Supabase.
What I want the BaaS to manage is:

Authentication across multiple providers (Google, Facebook/Instrgram, iOS,email and phone).
Push notification cross platforms.

I have quite a constrained budget of about $60 a month.
Scenario 1:
Host my Django app and database on Digital Ocean it's quite affordable.
Then choose supabase to do my Authetication and push notifications.
I like this setup also because my API and database can be in the same same datacenter and use an internal IP, significantly reducing my latency.
Even the few times I need to interact with Supabase are wide and far in between. Basically during signup, signin and push notifications.
With this scenario how would I would I get Supabase to work with Django user authentication?
What should I be concerned about with this setup from a smooth user experience or security?
If anyone has great articles that can assist with this it would be great.
Scenario 2:
I ignore the BaaS and manage authentication providers and Push Notifications on a case by case basis.
What this means is downloading each react native package for those 3rd party authentications and coercing them into Django friendly schemas.
This greatly simplifies my architecture but increases the amount of things I need to build / things that can go wrong.
If anyone has great resources of how they used react native and Django to do authentication especially i will be grateful.
Any advice would be great.

Did you move forward with this architecture for your side project?

I ended up going with all of it but swapped Supabase for Firebase. Simply because it a more mature product with a lot more examples.
I went with scenario 1 for the most part. Django allAuth is a helpful library still working on it.

Firebase sounds like a good fit for those use cases. I've used Supabase as an alternative to Django and Firebase, but not with Django yet. You may not need django-allauth at all if you're using Firebase. How are you trying to use them together?
